# What do the three checkboxes on the Interface translation import mean?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

When importing a *.po* file at /admin/config/regional/translate/import

What do these three options mean?

- Treat imported strings as custom translations
- Overwrite non-customized translations
- Overwrite existing customized translations

Answer (score 2):

- ***Treat imported strings as custom translations***

Will add to the Site the translations strings present in the .po file as custom translations.

- ***Overwrite non-customized translations***

All the strings that comes in the .po file will overwrite the existing translations that are not customized in the Site.

- ***Overwrite existing customized translations***

The customized translations present in the Site will be overwrite with the translations present in the .po file.

Comment: What is a _customized_ and _non-customized_ translation?

Comment: @24ma13wg the question in your previous comment should be a NEW quesion, are you going to post that soon? If not I might do so ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens sure go ahead. I can see that there is a column in the {locales_target} table called _customized_, which takes a boolean value, but I don't know what it means?

Comment: @24ma13wg As Pierre.Vriens says I think that your question is answered here, but now you're asking another different thing, so I think that you can accept the answer here and write another question. If you do it, let me know.